# Stop service loop from activity

Tags: android, service

I have activity, that starts/stops a service. And a service, that has a loop. I am currently trying to stop my service from main activity. I tried many variants but none calls onDestroy :/. Any help, thoughts or teachings will be appreciated. :)

**Part from my main activity where I try to stop a service with dialog:**

```
private void AlertDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Delete entry")
        .setMessage("Are you sure?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                  stopService(intent);
            }
         })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
                // do nothing
            }
         })
         .show();
```

**service:**

```
public class SensMessageService extends Service{

public final String APP = "Ultimator";
public final String PREF_IN_USE = "inuse";
public final String PREF_TOTAL_MESSAGES = "totalmes";
public final String PREF_LEFT_MESSAGES = "leftmes";
public final String MESSAGE_BODY = "sms_body";
public final String MESSAGE_RECEIVER = "sms_receiver";
public final String MESSAGE_REPEATS = "sms_repeats";
public final String TAG = "SensMessageService";

private IBinder ibinder;

private SharedPreferences prefrences;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return this.ibinder;
}


public class LocalBinder extends Binder{

    SensMessageService getBinder(){
        return SensMessageService.this;
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

@Override
public void unbindService(ServiceConnection conn) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.unbindService(conn);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intentas, int startId) {
    final Intent intent = intentas;

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            int repeat = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_REPEATS));
            String sendTo = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_RECEIVER);
            String myMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_BODY);

            for (int i=0; i<repeat; i++) {

                smsManager.sendTextMessage(sendTo, null, myMessage, null, null);
            }

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
```

}

I think onDestroy is not being called somehow :/, because I don't see a toast

**UPDATE:**

I added a thread, but somehow it does not print out

```
   @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while(true) {
                                sleep(1000);
                               System.out.println("fff");
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                thread.start();
```

Comment: Please post your Service code also.

Comment: also remove the `stopself` from `onDestroy`. In onDestroy means the service is already being stop. So calling `stopself` has no effect.

Comment: It looks like the onStart loop will take a fraction of a second to complete. Are you sure the service hasn't already stopped (completed) by the time you are trying to stop it from your activity?

Comment: Hmm could be if sending message task is being done not from the service itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `onStart()` has been deprecated for about four years. Please use `onStartCommand()`.

Second, please do your SMS work in a background thread, not the main application thread as you are doing presently.

Third, do not call `stopSelf()` in `onDestroy()`. If your service reaches `onDestroy()`, you do not need `stopSelf()`.

With respect to your reported problem, your entire loop will be processed before `onDestroy()` is called, as you have it implemented now. That is because both `onStart()` and `onDestroy()` are called on the main application thread, as is the `onClick()` method of your dialog. A thread can only do one thing at a time, and so long as you are tying up the main application thread with your SMS-sending loop, you will not be able to press the button and you will not be able to stop the service.

If you move the SMS-sending logic into a background thread, then in `onDestroy()` you can do something to cause that thread to terminate (e.g., have the thread watch an `AtomicBoolean`, which you flip from `onDestroy()`).

Comment: So my only way is to place it in a thread with sleep function? Because when I try to stop service sms sending "tasks" are already above service influence?

Answer (score 2):

You don't see a toast because you are using `getApplicationContext()`.
Put a `Log.e("myservice", "sadsad")` in `onDestroy()` instead to check if it's called

Comment: Because of flooded logcat I can't see if log shows up :/. When sending sms is started log cats is being flooded with variety of information

Comment: You can setup a filter in the logcat window

Answer (score 1):

When you call `stopService(intent);` it surely does call `onDestroy()` of your `Service`. The problem might be that you are not Runnable/Thread in `onDestroy()` of your Service. So calling `stopSelf();` inside `onDestroy()` of Service doesn't make any sense because `onDestroy()` will only be called when Service is stopped.

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding service then calling `stopService` will not stop the service until you explicitly call `unbindService(connection);` from your `Activity`. From the docs 
`Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed`

see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: I get "service not registered" force close.